# Get all elements between element type (h1's) and wrap in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal, siblings

I have the below structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <h2>subtitle 1</h2>
    <p>aaa</p>
    <p>bbb</p>
    <p>ccc</p>
    <h2>subtitle2</h2>
    <p>ddd</p>

    <h1>Header 2</h1>
    <h2>subtitle 3</h2>
    <p>eee</p>
    <p>fff</p>

</div>
```

I want to select all the h1 and p elements between each h1 and wrap in a div, so I end up with:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <h2>subtitle 1</h2>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>bbb</p>
        <p>ccc</p>
        <h2>subtitle2</h2>
        <p>ddd</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Header 2</h1>
        <h2>subtitle 3</h2>
        <p>eee</p>
        <p>fff</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried various things like the below, but none work perfectly:

```
$( "h1" ).prevUntil( "h1" ).wrapAll( "<div></div>" );
```

Comment: Why would you use [`prevUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil) when you're trying to find the elements that follow the `<h1>` element (until the next `<h1>`? I'd suggest switching that for [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shall use [.each jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to accomplish.

```
$("h1").each(function(){})
```

2. `.prevUntil` will inverse the Dom node traversing, use `.nextUntil` instead.
3. as to match the end-up output, the script is as follows:

```
<script>
    $("h1").each(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil( "h1" ).wrapAll( "<div></div>" );
        // uncomment the two lines to move the h1 inside the wrapped div
        // const el = $(this).next();
        // $(this).prependTo(el);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this is close but it wraps the h1 inside the new div as well. I want the div to be under the h1. Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually if you remove the last two lines (the 'const el' and '$(this)' lines), this works perfectly! I'll accept it as the answer if you remove those lines

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution where it gets all the children and then if its a h1 tag it will create a new div and move H1 and other children into it

```js
    var newDiv;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".wrapper").children().each(function(){
           if($(this).is("h1")){
              $(this).before("<div></div>");
              newDiv =  $(this).prev();
              newDiv.append($(this));
           }else{
            newDiv.append($(this));
           }
        });
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

        <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <h2>subtitle 1</h2>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>bbb</p>
        <p>ccc</p>
        <h2>subtitle2</h2>
        <p>ddd</p>

        <h1>Header 2</h1>
        <h2>subtitle 3</h2>
        <p>eee</p>
        <p>fff</p>
 
</div>
```